# Create New Tab on Team's newly created channel is not available using Application delegation access token

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I was trying to create new tab (which is sharepoint library) onto newly created channel. 
And I could not use the $accessToken with application delegated permission but only user delegation was only available. Is there anyway to use Application delegation permission for creating new tab?

$apiUrl2 =   "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/"+ $groups.id +"/channels/" +  $newChannelID + "/tabs"

$Data2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $accessToken -Uri $apiUrl2 -Body $body -Method POST -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you please confirm if your token has required permissions (use https://jwt.io/#debugger-io)? Also, when you say newly created channel does this mean it's working for older channels?

Comment: Hello Wajeed, oh sorry. Same to old channel! and I already granted Site/Groups permission from AAD -> API permission properly :(

Comment: Could you please share the error message/exception?